# How to pass the real value while iterate the loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I think the problem is really clear. This is my code:

```
 // Add markers for each spot
 for(var spot of spots) {

   var spotId: number = +spot.id;
   console.log(spotId);

   // Add marker for current spot
   L.marker([spot.latitude, spot.longitude], {icon: this.mapService.getSchoolIcon() })
     .addTo(this.map)
     .on('click', () => console.log('CLICKED: ' + spotId)  );
 }
```

And this is the output in the console if I click all pins:

```
1
2
3
4
CLICKED: 4
CLICKED: 4
CLICKED: 4
CLICKED: 4
```

Comment: If you are writing TypeScript, why not use `let`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html

Comment: Since JS doesn't have block scope, only function scope, you only create `spotId` once and then all other iterations of the loop use (and modify) the same `spotId`. Refer to Sushanth's answer.

Comment: it's because of closure, to print respective number you need to do either of the following modification, 
- you could use `let` instead of `var`
- or you can use self executing anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `var spotId` with `let spotId` should fix the issue as it will make `spotId` a block scope variable.

Comment: Thank you, this also works for me. I think this would be the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

It the case of classic closure problem.

To solve we generally pass the arg to the scope, which forms a closure at the time of excecution.

```
(function(scopedSpotId) {
    return function() {
       console.log('CLICKED: ' + scopedSpotId); 
    }
}(spotId))
```

You will have to return a new function for each element in the loop.

```
((scopedSpotId) ->
  ->
    console.log 'CLICKED: ' + scopedSpotId
    return
) spotId
```

Comment: If you want, you can add this working code as an example: L.marker([spot.latitude, spot.longitude], {icon: this.mapService.getSchoolIcon() })
        .addTo(this.map)
        .on('click', (function(scopedSpotId) {
          return function() {
             console.log('CLICKED: ' + scopedSpotId);
          }
      }(spotId))  );